# pycharm maximize current editor like tmux zoom

Tags: pycharm, tmux

In Tmux

[image]

I can press `prefix + z` to maximize current pane

[image]

Now in Pycharm I have multiple panes too,
[image]

And I wish to have same functionality as in Tmux. Best I have found is `ctrl + shift + f12` to hide all beside editors panes. Is there some hope?

Comment: View -> Appearance -> Enter Distraction Free Mode and View -> Appearance -> Enter Full Screen

Comment: @pjcunningham sadly, it doesn't expand the current pane/tab to hide the other panes/tabs. I want to focus on just ONE file at a time. Much like the OP. But I also want to revert back to my original splits when I am done with needing that focus, (just like Zoom in Tmux)